# Ubuntu, accidentally removed all file rights from users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

While trying to restrict home folders to sudo users (then give a user access to one folder) I accidentally executed this command:

`sudo chmod go-rwx /*/`

Which removed access rights to all folders for all users, except the root account. I can't do anything currently on non-root accounts (no cd, ls, nano etc). How can I change folder permissions back to default where users had access to /home/ and program directories?

**Note:** I haven't really tried anything yet as I don't want to break things further.

Answer (score 1):

About the only thing you can do is find out what the permissions were before and set them back.  You might try installing another copy of Linux on a spare machine or VM to get the permission bits.  Here are the permissions from one of my machines to get you started.  Good luck.

```
cd /
chmod 1777 tmp
chmod 555 proc sys
chmod 700 lost+found
chmod 750 root
chmod 755 bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt opt run sbin share srv usr var
```

Comment: I managed to change all the folders to the permissions you said (they are the same my friend also has with a similar setup so they look right). Certain things don't appear to work properly, such has tabbing to auto complete, and most importantly, no new SSH connections can be established. I assume this is because some of the permissions or groups are wrong.

Comment: Is it possible you changed permissions at more than just the root directory?  Try running (as root) `getfacl -R / >/var/tmp/perms` on your friend's computer, copy /var/tmp/perms file to your machine, then `cd /; setfacl --restore=/var/tmp/perms` on your machine.  This will copy the permission bits from all the files on his computer to yours.  This won't be perfect, but it might get you further along.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I didn't have you set the permissions on the root directory itself.  Normally / has 755 permissions, so that would be `chmod 755 /`.  Normally that wouldn't be affected by /*/ pattern, but it might if you have bash's dotglob setting enabled (shopt -s dotglob).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @virtex and I furthermore recommend you, in case the permissions he shared with you didn't solved the issue, to try again writing the literal-additive form of the second argument in `chmod` and, in the worst of the cases, using the recursive `-R` option.

This is, as last choice use `chmod -R u+rwx /lost+found` instead of `chmod 700 /lost+found` (for example).

PS: It happened to me once that I changed permissions in `/` and then decided to solved the problem easy-peasy by reinstalling the whole system. But, of course, this is kind of a drastic solution...

Comment: I am thinking about re-installing the system, I'd just rather not have the hassle of re-installing all my software again.

Comment: If you don't have your setting hyper-customized, go for it. You should feel cozy in less than 2 hours.